# How to get objects from worklight JSONStore where value of specific attribute attribute is null or empty

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

How can I get all the objects from JSONSTore where the value of specified attribute is null.
I have tried to specify the value of attribute as empty or null but not able to get the result. 
I have to implement the below SQL query in IBM Worklight to get data from JSONStore.

select * from employee where age IS NULL

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have something like this in your search fields: `{value: 'string'}`.

Then add data like this: `WL.JSONStore.get('collection').add({value: 'NULL'})`.

Then search for it like this: `WL.JSONStore.get('collection').find({value: 'NULL'})`.

It is not currently possible to search for things that are not `string`, `integer`, `number` or `boolean`. Notice that `'NULL'` is a string in my examples above.

Feature requests [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014907906&ps=25).

Comment: Thanks Cnandreu for quick response. Yes that field in in search fields and value of this field is '' in JSONStore. But on finding with {'name' : '') it return all objects even the value of name is not null. name is of string.

Comment: It is working fine if I queried using the advancedFind and QuertPart and I am able to get the expected result. But not working with normal find() function. Might be this is issue with the find().